# Check if clicked class has a certain ID

Tags: jquery, html

How to check if the clicked `class` is corresponding to a certain `ID`?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" href="#">Alle machines</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="laser" href="#">Lasersnijden</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Change class on click
    $(".nav-link").click(function() {
        $('.nav-link').removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass("active");

        if($(this) == document.getElementById('laser')) { alert("Laser clicked."); }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: change this code `if($(this) == document.getElementById('laser'))` to `if($(this).get(0) == document.getElementById('laser'))`

Comment: @gijoe can you explain `.get(0)1` ?

Comment: @Muiter inside the function $(this) references a jquery object and calling $(this).get(0) you can get the dom element that the jquery object manipulates . Now document.getElementById returns also a dom element directly, so in order to compare them and find them equally you need to call $(this).get(0) and compare this value with the document.getElementById

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation @gijoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` returns a jQuery Object that wraps the DOM object

where as

`document.getElementById('laser')` returns a HTML DOM object.

Clearly they are not same. If you use `$(this)`, you have to use index like:

```
if($(this)[0] == document.getElementById('laser'))
```

```js
// Change class on click
$(".nav-link").click(function() {
  $('.nav-link').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass("active");
  if($(this)[0] == document.getElementById('laser')) { 
    alert("Laser clicked."); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" href="#">Alle machines</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="laser" href="#">Lasersnijden</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Though instead of checking the whole object, you can simply check the `id`

```js
// Change class on click
$(".nav-link").click(function() {
  $('.nav-link').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass("active");
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'laser') { 
    alert("Laser clicked."); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" href="#">Alle machines</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="laser" href="#">Lasersnijden</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this of jQuery like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-link").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active')
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        if(id == 'laser'){
            alert("laser clicked")
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" href="#">Alle machines</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="laser" href="#">Lasersnijden</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```